# How would I go about making my own spherecast function?

Tags: lua, unity-game-engine, raycasting, roblox

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html
I would imagine it's basically raycasting, but in almost all directions.

A ray in this instance would be created like so:

```
Ray.new(Vector3.new(x,y,z)  -- origin
Vector3.new(x,y,z))         -- direction
```

Clarification: I'm creating a disco ball on roblox that rotates 360 degrees continually. Each time the ball rotates about a degree or so it sends rays out in almost all directions. These rays record the position of any points of contact using FindPartOnRay(ray). From there I am placing a light on the position that I got from FindPartOnRay(ray).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start to implement it something along the lines of this:

```
function spherecast(radius, centre, objects)
   local hits = {}

   for i, obj in pairs(objects) do
      local d = radius + obj.size
      local dx = obj.x - centre.x
      local dy = obj.y - centre.y
      local dz = obj.z - centre.z
      local sqrdist = dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz
      if sqrdist <= d * d then
         table.insert(hits, obj)
      end
   end
   return hits
end
```

I know you may want more info about the collisions but as a first round, this will be very fast. `obj.size` is the maximum dimension (width, height, depth).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this function does. I'll tell you what exactly I'm doing, and then maybe you can tell me how to use this function to complete my goal, or recommend me to another way of doing it. I'm creating a disco ball on roblox that rotates 360 degrees continually. Each time the ball rotates about a degree or so it sends rays out in almost all directions. These rays record the position of any obstacles using FindPartOnRay(ray). From there I am placing a light on the position that I got from FindPartOnRay(ray).

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be the following:

Having a disco ball AND a fixed point for the source of light, that will send rays to the ball, it should be easy to get the current angle of each of these rays on the balls surface. At every hit point of a light ray on the balls surface, you send another ray in the inverted angle (must be taken from the normal of the disco balls surface at the hit point) into your room. There, where these rays of the reflected light hit something in the room, you can show glowing spots.

You could use a raster for all these direct light rays from the virtual light source, that go to the disco ball. In this case you only use Physics.Raycast.

To simulate a rotation of the ball, you could continuously move these rays slowly to one side. You should then have moving spots in your room. Disco!